# View number of glyphs in a given font for Linux

Tags: linux, fonts

For a given `ttf` or `otf` font, how to get meta information? Information such as how many glyphs were used, what tool was used, what version of font we have, its label, etc? 
For windows machine, I have seen [this tool](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=ViewGlyph_home). But for Ubuntu/Linux, I couldn't find any!

Comment: Related: [Finding out what characters a given font supports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4458696/12892) from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that you can use. You will need Perl and the `libfont-ttf-perl` package from Debian (or [Font::TTF](https://metacpan.org/pod/Font::TTF) from CPAN) :

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
    
use Font::TTF::Font;
    
unless (defined $ARGV[0]) {
    die <<~'EOT';
        perl glyphs_counter.pl infontfile.otf
        Prints glyph count for each input TTF file
        EOT
}

foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $f = Font::TTF::Font->open($_) || die "Unable to open font file $_";
    my $num = $f->{'maxp'}{'numGlyphs'};
    printf "%6d  %s\n", $num, $_;
    $f->release;
}
```

The only thing you need to do is to save this script to a file,  call it throught Perl and give it as a parameter the path of the font you want to count the glyphs :

```
$ perl glyphs_counter.pl /path/to/the/foo_font.ttf
```

It seems to work for TTF and OTF formats. Hope it helps.

2022 edit: removed the link pointing to the original script that I copied this solution from, since the link was broken, and I couldn't find an archive of it.

Comment: Doesn't work as of now: `$ perl glyphs_counter.pl Times-Roman.ttf` yields `Can't find string terminator "EOT" anywhere before EOF at glyphs_counter.pl line 5.` Same with an OFT font.

Comment: … and the suppiled URL is dead.

Comment: I updated the script and tested it... Seems to work on Ubuntu. Do you have Font::TTF::Font installed @GeekestGeek ?

Comment: Yes. After your update, your script works like a charm. Thank you! Could you repair the URL, too, perhaps? Or remove the URL, if non-repairable?

Comment: @GeekestGeek not repairable unfortunately since the Google Group has been removed. Can't find an archive of it, so I'll delete the link. Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66788946/3585790

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f "$1" ]] && fc='fc-query' || fc='fc-match'

for range in $($fc --format='%{charset}\n' "$1"); do
    for n in $(seq "0x${range%-*}" "0x${range#*-}"); do
        printf "\n"
    done
done | wc -l
```

Probably you don't need anything to install.

You can use it like:

```
$ count-glyphs /usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
1485
$ count-glyphs "Noto Color Emoji"
1485
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python script which will process the `charset` output of some `fc-*` tools.

```python
# Usage:
# fc-match --format '%{charset}\n' FONT_NAME | python3 count-charset.py
# fc-query --format '%{charset}\n' FONT_FILE | python3 count-charset.py

import sys

def count_range(expr: str) -> int:
    if '-' in expr:
        (a, b) = expr.split('-')
        return int(b, base=16) - int(a, base=16) + 1
    return 1

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(sum(count_range(expr) for expr in line.strip().split()))
```

Examples:

```sh
$ fc-match --format '%{charset}\n' 'GoMono Nerd Font' | python3 count-charset.py
11786

$ fc-query --format '%{charset}\n' /usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeMono.otf | python3 count-charset.py
4160
```